# Siebel Open UI Environment

Tags: oracle, crm, environment, siebel

I am looking for a quick and easy way to setup Siebel Open UI so that I can test it out before implementing it in my company's environment.  We are currently using 8.1.1.5 and are interested in upgrading to 8.1.1.9.  We have heard that Siebel Open UI will allow you to use the CRM in Google chrome and other browsers.  We also heard there is more freedom to change the UI and that we don't have to stick with the SWSE templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Bloomspire](http://www.bloomspire.com).  They can easily set up Siebel environments including 8.1.1.9.  They are a lot cheaper than Oracle's cloud solution.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to Bloomspire.  This is what my company is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link for Oracle Siebel VM. This will give you a Siebel 8.1.1 version which you will have to upgrade to the latest available IP. (8.1.1.10 is the latest available as on this date)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/siebel-092480.html

Answer (score 0):

[How about using the VM oracle provides?](https://blogs.oracle.com/dipock/entry/siebel_811_on_oracle_vm_now_av)

Comment: I looked on their website but couldn't find it.  Can you send a link?  Also, do you know if it costs extra?

Answer (score 0):

VM sounds like a good idea, but i too couldn't find those on delivery. Oracle now has cumulative 8.1.1.9 installation, meaning you only need to install it once, and it will have OpenUI. Unfortunately, OpenUI is still work in progress, so you need to apply a lot of HotFixes to make it work properly. Unfortunately , Oracle doesn't provide any way to apply them un-attended, so there is no way around some manual patching.

Answer (score 0):

We've just been through an internal upgrade for OpenUI, and now running 8.1.1.10

Seems that the jump from .9 to .10 is a major hurdle..

If you are still in need of assistance, feel free to contact me.

David - www.crmantra.com